# Writng delegate for UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have implemented UIActivityViewController.After selecting save or delete draft in mail application it is returning true in completion handler.

```
activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *act, BOOL done) {
NSString *serviceMsg = nil;
if ([act isEqualToString:UIActivityTypeMail]) {
if (done)
NSLog("%s",mail sent);//on deleting or saving draft it is returning true
else
NSLog("%s",mail not sent);
}
```

Can i have separate delegate for mailApplication....

Comment: yes you can delegate is depending on developer mind

Comment: how i can assign delagate for mail activity of UIActivityViewController

Comment: how to solve the problem.....i mean eventhough on saving draft of sending mail it is returning true for mail activity...

Answer (score 0):

yes you can but it not possible to if you are using mailing service in different places.So use  mail service using Singleton patten So you can use this service in your others class also.

Comment: is it an ios bug where it mail activity returns true even though mail is not sent i.e., when saving the draft